# Take snapshot of canvas and display it on separate HTML page with only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take a capture of a HTMLCanvasElement, and display that result on a separate web page without uploading the image to a server. My initial thought was to save the image to local storage as a base64 image data URI, but then I looked at the uncompressed image size of the images that will be being used. @ 1920x1080 pixes, it might be around 6MB (using Photoshop to show the uncompressed size, since I didn't find a better way yet). The information I found on [size limits for local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) made me think this was a bad idea.

So trying to find another solution, I've looked into using [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Browser_compatibility), and saving that to the [HTML5 DOM File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). But then I found Microsoft Edge doesn't support `toBlob()` on canvas elements.

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085/1253298) regarding the use of the new File API, but then I found that's not supported in IE 11.

I need to support recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Explorer 11 and Edge.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Is it possible, or should I just upload it to a server?

Comment: Does it have to be on a different web page? Or can you hide a bunch of stuff and make it look like it is a new page?

Comment: The source of the image is from a page that is running intensive processes, that will hinder performance of what we will be doing with the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stay on the same page, and just make it look like a new page then you can do the following:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10,10,300,220);
var img = new Image();
img.src    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.body.append(img);
```

```css
canvas, img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="320" height="240">
</canvas>
```

I'm not sure how to save it off to get to the new page. But try using `toDataURL` to get the image data since that works back to IE9